# What to do if you're being abused by a Low Cost company?

Tags: air-travel, legal, low-cost-carriers

Recently I was denied a receipt, when I had to pay a fine to an LC company for not complying with all their rules.

I can understand the strict rules in order to keep competitive prices. In other hand they fail a lot on their obligations. I needed a receipt as a proof of payment and that was denied. After insisting I was told I could get one e-mailing the company (interesting situation… how could I prove the payment?) Other, more extreme  situations happen, like lack of support to passengers when there are large delays on flights.

It's becoming more and more frequent. Rules are becoming a lot more strict with airlines (not only with LC). The customer is the weakest link and is in a very vulnerable position on an airport, specially if already standing next to the gate. What can one do in such a situation?

Comment: *On the other hand I don't understand how we pay for instance 50€, like I did, and don't get a receipt or any other proof of payment* - Did you pay cash?  Furthermore what are you trying to defend against?

Comment: I did pay cash. They don't usually give you many options to pay. But that depends from place to place. I would like to get a receipt for instance. Their answer was that I should contact the company by mail and request that. How do I prove the payment than?

Comment: That's why you only pay by credit card.

Comment: Which country was this in?

Comment: It was in Spain

Comment: O that is simple, don't fly Low cost.

Comment: @Karlson: Ah, but guess what?  They often have *extra* fees for payment by credit card.

Comment: I'm confused. We all hate the draconian rules the LCCs have, but they're there in plain text to read beforehand.  What exactly are you defending yourself against? It was you who put yourself in said delicate position, no?
Myself and all my friend in London reguarly swore we would never fly again with RyanAir with their fees, rules and so on, but then we'd see their cheap ads and go "oh one more time".  You get what you pay for, unfortunately.  
However, a receipt should have been provided.  I'd definitely contact their complaints department, or include them in a tweet - surprisingly effective!

Comment: I am fine with rules, but they go a bit beyond what's reasonable . I updated my question to give another example that I saw. Basically I want to know what mechanisms we can use to complain. Preferably one that is efficient. The receipt is just one situation but they fail in many others, namely on giving support to passengers when their flights are delayed longer than reasonable and established by rules. In the case of the invoice I could complain to local authorities, but I am flying and not returning so soon.

Comment: Some cheap airlines are worse than the others, and I always try to avoid the worse one :)

Comment: @Grzenio lol.. carefull there, the second story told  didn't happen with the worse one... things are getting stricter.

Comment: @NateEldredge The fees are not > 10 euro are they?

Comment: Low cost carriers, just as the high cost ones have clear rules. And what's nice with the low cost carriers is that they enforce them and everybody knows it. One bag is one bag and not two. 50 cm are 50 cm and not 53. It's as easy as that.

Comment: These rules are one reason why LCC are cheap. The people who read the rules profit from those who don't. I don't see anything unfair here, and especially nothing to defend against.

Comment: @Feklee that's just not true! They were already cheap before enforcing these rules. They just realized that they could raise their profit and not even care that much about the customer. Your reaction proves that. I could expect people to tolerate these behaviours, but defend them as the holly grail for cheapness is a bit ridiculous. Because it's cheap (is it?) the passenger will just accept everything. I am not the one saying this, it's the "boss" of the largest carrier.

Comment: LCCs are a bit like convenience stores. There are pros and cons. Everybody bitches about the cons but they could've just gone for a fullprice airline or supermarket. But they were lured in by the low cost or convenience and don't want to blame themself for doing so. There's no such thing as a free lunch so learn the pifalls and consider the alternatives. If you know what you're doing then LCCs can be very low cost and convenience stores can be very convenenient. But LCCs are never flexible and convenience stores are never cheap.

Comment: I have made over 500 flights on business in the last 15 years, and with one notable exception, the hassles with low cost airlines made it much cheaper for me to always fly with a proper airline. On a flexible economy ticket. Otherwise at some point you will get screwed, because they know they can charge for ALL changes from the basic ticket. (for info - I had 3 months of twice-weekly EasyJet flights Edinburgh to Heathrow, bought in advance. All were perfect :-)

Comment: I'm surprised by how many comments blame the user before blaming companies that only care about profit, and have absolutely no moral concerns about using very confusing rules with the sole aim of tricking people. The incredibly low prices of these companies make it impossible for others to compete with them, so it's chosing between a borderline scam (shady rules, confusing terminology, difficulty to access information) or EU350 to fly 100 miles. Also, isn't denying a receipt illegal in most countries?

Comment: Too late now, but if I need a receipt, I get one or I don't pay.

Comment: @WGroleau it's annoying but back than they were in a dominant position. They won't allow you to board and face an hard situation.

Answer (score 7):

Normally what you describe falls under [Consumer Protection laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_protection) in the country where this occurred.

Given that this is Spain you should be able to find relevant information on the [European Consumer Center in Spain](http://www.cec.consumo-inc.es/index.php?lang=en) site.

But generally speaking you should use electronic payment methods if you want to keep track of your payments and have record of it in case things go awry.

Answer (score 5):

best way is to read the terms of your contract and learn to understand them, then handle accordingly.
There's a 50 Euro fee for oversized bags, you either don't bring an oversized bag or you bring the money, it's that simple. Nothing to understand, nothing to "defend yourself against".
If you're one of those people who're prone to want to board an aircraft with tons and tons of stuff that's over the amount allowed on your ticket and then get upset when confronted with that, I can't have any sympathy with you and your ilk as you're a main reason for delays, overloaded overhead bins, diversions because of fuel shortages (yes, the airline needs to carry extra fuel for contingencies, but you wanting to take 100lbs of carryon luggage and stuff it in bins designed to take the luggage of 3-4 people rather than just you is NOT a contingency), frustration among your fellow passengers who have to sit with their luggage in their lap for hours because yours takes up the space designed to hold their bag, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: I read the rules and I am aware of them though they are not so clear as the companies state. Websites can be very obscure in the buying process.

I am not talking about situations where people are taking 100 bags into the plain. I am just talking in abuse from someone in a dominant position beyond what's reasonable. I think you miss the point here.

Comment: oh, I get the point. But 1) it's no abuse and is by definition reasonable to you as long as your contract of travel covers it (if not, demand to see a supervisor) and 2) "what's reasonable" varies per person, apparently a lot of people think it quite reasonable for themselves to carry 100 bags but think others should not (of course, they need the room).

Comment: @jwenting It is pretty weird that you just pay €50 cash, and don't get a receipt whatsoever. What is holding the next guy back from charging you another 50 euro's? Also, your fuel argument makes more sense with respect to oversized passenger than for oversized bags.

Comment: @Bernhard not sure about receipts, never had to deal with that situation. A luggage tag for oversized luggage could be seen as a receipt though. As to oversized passengers, they're already made to buy 2 seats.

Comment: @jwenting - I did ask for a supervisor, but then you have peer pressure from the other passenger that just want to go into the plain (and I really understand them) and you risk missing the flight. That's what I mean when I say you're in a vulnerable situation.

Comment: @jwenting Good answer. It says what many of us think!

Comment: This is somewhat naive. Low-cost airlines frequently 'announce' that they will impose a fee, or refuse compensation, when the law doesn't allow them to ( www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1267804/Iceland-volcano-Ryanair-WILL-pay-compensation-ash-victim-passengers.html); they will continue to get away with it till somebody challenges them.

Comment: and the gate is not the place to do so... Challenge them in court, or tell your representatives in government about it and have them get your government to file charges against the airline. To simply ignore the rules of your contract and then whine and complain about being refused boarding is beyond silly.

Comment: @nsn: strictly speaking, it's not an abuse if it's in the contract you signed when you buy your ticket, however unreasonable you think that may be. It would be an abuse if they say your bag is 53cm when it's actually 49cm, or if they claim that the size limit is 50cm while on your ticket it says 55cm, or if regulation specifies at least 55cm but your carrier uses 50cm. If you don't like it, you shouldn't have signed the contract in the first place. Many higher cost carriers ignored minor infractions of their rules, that does not mean that you should be entitled to do that with other carriers.

Comment: @jwenting fair enough, I agree with you. But what if the company fails to support you in the airport in case of a delay (large of course), like has happened before?

Comment: complain afterwards, don't make life more miserable for your fellow passengers than it is already, and for the gate agents who have no control over delays anyway, by constantly whining and complaining, screaming how "your rights are being violated", etc. etc., and if things are really bad, maybe quietly approach airport management about things, or seek the phone number of the airlines complaints department that you given your hostility towards airlines no doubt carry with you at all times, and call that from a quiet corner.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just remembered that I once noticed that one of the cheap airlines defined the maximum dimensions of the hand luggage which was 5cm smaller than the equivalent in British Airways. In this case even if the passenger has "hand-luggage approved" suitcase, there is a fair chance it will be too big for the cheap airline. This is probably what happened in the case described in the question.

How to defend yourself? I guess you need to read all the small print, but I understand it is very time consuming, especially that these things change.

Comment: With Wizzair, you have to pay 10 € for your cabin luggage if it's larger than 42 x 32 x 25 cm (but it still must be smaller than 56 x 45 x 25 cm). They did worse than Ryanair, it's not easy!

Comment: @travelot, I have seen this one as well!